# CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoapods

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements: - Nudgespot (~> 2.3) required by Podfile - Nudgespot (~> 2.6) required by Podfile None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: Nudgespot (~> 2.3). You have either: * out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update. * mistyped the name or version. * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile. Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, pod repo update does not happen on pod install by default.

Comment: That's good, try to run the pod repo update standalone.

Comment: not worked for me